# Invalid Html tags nesting

Tags: html, user-interface, nested, tags, anchor

Following is an example of invalid html tag nesting.

This is not correct and should never be done because the p tag has been
        abused

What are other examples of such invalid nesting? Also how one can verify code structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
 <div>some words</div>
</p>
```

The above code gives the error which you mentioned.

An authoritative place to look for allowed containment relations is the HTML spec. See, for example, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html. It specifies which elements are block elements and which are inline. For those lists, search for the section marked "HTML content models".

For the P element, it specifies the following, which indicates that P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."